# segment em with known data opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I use opencv [EM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html) algorithm for segment an image into 2 shapes.
One shape is always inside.  I use [EM segment](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html).

I want to use some known model of RGB colors: I have input table of 30*3 which is common colors for the background. How to input this to EM? should I calculate means and std and input to the constructor?

```
Python: cv2.EM.trainE(samples, means0[, covs0[, weights0[, logLikelihoods[, labels[, probs]]]]]) → retval, logLikelihoods, labels, probs
Python: cv2.EM.trainM(samples, probs0[, logLikelihoods[, labels[, probs]]])
```

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `cv.EM.trainE` interface and provide the algorithm with you initial `30x3` values as `means0` input argument.